# Titan Graph DB over DynamoDB coding

Tags: java, graph, amazon-dynamodb, titan

I'm trying this first time. I followed the steps in [Amazon Documentation For Titan Graph](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.TitanDB.DownloadingAndRunning.html)

I looked at the example code that was provided but found that it has no starting point. How can i code using TitanGraph class the adding of each Vertex and each edge? Is there a way i can instantiate TitanGraph object? I am guessing that i don't have to deal with DynamoDB API at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 in the link you had referenced their GitHub site where you can find some example code. https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/1.0.0/src/main/java/com/amazon/titan/example/MarvelGraphFactory.java

And the graph configuration files are located in the same repo https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/tree/1.0.0/src/test/resources

You can instantiate a TitanGraph like this:

```
TitanGraph Graph = TitanFactory.open("dynamodb.properties");
```

Comment: Thanks! i found it.